# Cite multiple figure parts in latex

Tags: floats, citing, ref

I am working on ieee template on overleaf. I have figures with (a) and (b) part but how can I cite fig. 1(a) and (b) in document. For simple ref we use `\ref{figurelabel}` but for a and b part how to cite ...

here is my code:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makecell}%
%table
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{times}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\removelatexerror}{\let\@latex@error\@gobble}
\makeatother
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
        \centering
        \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.48\linewidth} % <---
\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
\subfloat[ aaa ]{\includegraphics{Fig5a.PNG}}\hfill
\label{Fig5a}
\subfloat [bbb]{ \includegraphics{Fig5b.PNG}}
 \caption{ccccc}
    \label{Fig5b}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
\subfloat[aaa]{\includegraphics{Fig6a.PNG}}\hfill
\label{Fig6a}
\subfloat[bbbb]{\includegraphics{Fig6b.PNG}}
 \caption{ccccccccccccccc}
\label{Fig6b}
\end{minipage}
  \end{figure*}
```

Comment: The IEEE provides several LaTeX document clases. Which one are you using?

Comment: You can put additional `\label` commands inside the argument of `\subfloat`, for example `\subfloat[aaa]{\label{abc}\includegraphics{Fig5a}}`.

Comment: thanks but how can i print Fig. 4 (a) and (b)  in in text citation. i used these commands Fig. 4 \label{Fig4ab} \label{Fig5a}
and \label{Fig5b} but iits only printing Fig. 4 not a and b

Comment: @Mico updated in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several missunderstandings in your given TeX Code ...

I have corrected them in the following mwe and marked important code changings with `<======`. Please see that I deleted some called packages and commands in your code which are not needed for this issue ...

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{times}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.48\linewidth} % <---
\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
\subfloat[aaa]{\label{fig:fig5a}\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfill % <=====
\subfloat[bbb]{\label{fig:fig5b}\includegraphics{example-image-a}} % <=========
\caption{ccccc}
\label{fig:figccccc} % <=======================================================
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
\subfloat[aaa]{\label{fig:fig6a}\includegraphics{example-image-b}}\hfill % <===
\subfloat[bbbb]{\label{fig:fig6b}\includegraphics{example-image}} % <==========
\caption{ccccccccccccccc}
\label{fig:figcccccc} % <======================================================
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
How to reference the image \ref{fig:figccccc} and \ref{fig:figcccccc} 
and the subimages \ref{fig:fig5a}, \ref{fig:fig5b}, \ref{fig:fig6a} 
and \ref{fig:fig6b}.
\end{document}
```

and its resulting pdfs:

[image: resulting referenes]

and the image

[image: resulting images]